# Combinar php con html

Tags: php, html, condiciones

Estoy comenzando con esto de la programación en PHP y tras estar trasteando un poco realizando algunas cosillas me ha surgido una duda.

Os dejo un ejemplo de código con algunas condiciones dónde estoy trasteando:

```
if ($mac_device === null) { 
echo "-- no se ha encontrado el vale o no está activo --";
} else {

foreach ($json_expired as $record) { 

    $mac = $record->mac;
    $status_expired = $record->expired;

    if ($mac_device === $mac) { 
        //echo "--[$mac]--";
        //echo "--[$mac_device]--";
        if ($status_expired != null) {
            echo "--EL VALE NO ESTA ACTIVO--"; 
            break;
        } else {
            echo "--EL VALE ESTA ACTIVO"; 
            $unifi_connection->unauthorize_guest($mac_device); 
            include 'create.php';
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

La duda que tengo es que si al combinar esto con HTML como os lo muestro a continuación ¿se interrumpe la ejecución del código PHP o todo se ejecutaría igual que sin el HTML que le he metido?:

```
<?php

if ($mac_device === null) { 
?>
<head>  
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "-- no se ha encontrado el vale o no está activo --";
?>

</body>     
<?php

} else {


foreach ($json_expired as $record) { 

    $mac = $record->mac;
    $status_expired = $record->expired;

    if ($mac_device === $mac) {             
        if ($status_expired != null) {

?>
<head>  
</head>
<body>

<?php
            echo "--EL VALE NO ESTA ACTIVO--";              
            break;
?>

</body>     
<?php           

        } else {


            echo "--EL VALE ESTA ACTIVO"; 
?>
<head>  
</head>
<body>

<?php           

            $unifi_connection->unauthorize_guest($mac_device); 
            include 'create.php';
            break;
        }
    }
}}

?>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se interrumpe. El fallo que tienes es que estás abriendo varios `<head>` y varios `<body>`. Y no es necesario.

Un código HTML consiste en:

```
<head>
<!-- Aquí especificamos estilos, scripts, etc.. -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Aquí introducimos el contenido de la web -->
</body>
```

Por lo tanto tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
if ($mac_device === null) { 
?>
<head>
<!-- Aquí especificamos estilos, etc. -->
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "-- no se ha encontrado el vale o no está activo --";    
} else {

foreach ($json_expired as $record) { 

    $mac = $record->mac;
    $status_expired = $record->expired;

    if ($mac_device === $mac) {             
        if ($status_expired != null) {

            echo "--EL VALE NO ESTA ACTIVO--";              
            break;         

        } else {

            echo "--EL VALE ESTA ACTIVO";            
            $unifi_connection->unauthorize_guest($mac_device); 
            include 'create.php';
            break;
        }
    }
}}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: Un placer, si te ha sido útil puedes marcarla como resuelta.

Comment: por lo que me dices y el código indicado, ¿se cumplirían las condiciones y se mostrarían los "echo" con los estilos y contenido especificado en el HTML?

Comment: Si quieres que los `echo` tengan estilo puedes hacer algo así: `echo "<span class='tu_clase'>--EL VALE ESTA ACTIVO<span>";` o puedes utilizar la etiqueta `<p>` de párrafo. La cuestión es que lo ubiques exactamente donde quieres que salta en tu HTML. Tal y como te lo he puesto en el ejemplo saldría arriba del todo a la izquierda, porque ese HTML no tiene ningún estilo ni secciones creadas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! voy ahora mismo a echarle un vistazo :D